# How to package a PySide/Phonon app under Mac OSX?

Tags: osx-lion, pyside, py2app, phonon

I have a PySide/Phonon app (developed for and working flawlessly on Windows) that I need to "port" to Mac OSX - where I have no development experience whatsoever.
The app works as expected if I just run the Python file - the problems arise when I try to package it (which I need to do) with py2app.

If I leave the resulting .app as is, Phonon doesn't work, because it fails to load the required phonon_backend ; if I add the plugin path to qt.conf, as various sources suggest, Phonon seems to load (that is, I don't get the corresponding error message anymore), but I start getting the "so-and-so library is loaded twice, one will be used, which one is undefined" error, and the app crashes right away.

Finally, if I try to use the macdeploy_qt tool, I receive a message to the effect of "no external framework" and the results are functionally equivalent to what I get without using the tool, except there are a few more plugins in the relevant directory.

Any ideas/pointers/tutorials/etc? I'm using PySide1.1.1 for Qt4.7, by the way, and Python.org python binaries (otherwise py2app can't even start to build a standalone app, it seems).

Comment: Well, seeing as I'm happily tumbleweeding around, I'll add that I tried using PyInstaller, with the same results: Libraries loaded twice, app not working. No amount of tinkering with qt.conf seemed to help, either.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you do it like [in this tutorial](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Packaging_PySide_applications_on_MacOS).

Then you just have to add the following line somewhere at the top of your main module:

```
QApplication.setLibraryPaths([os.path.join(os.environ['_MEIPASS2'], 'qt4_plugins'), os.environ['_MEIPASS2'] ])
```

For PyInstaller >1.5 the following code should be used instead:

```
QApplication.setLibraryPaths([os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, 'qt4_plugins'), sys._MEIPASS])
```

Comment: I suppose there's a difference in my setup, because I don't have the _MEIPASS2 variable set in my env...
Some further exploration led me to believe the problem is in my PATH: the value is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin` - I suspect that first bit is what screws stuff up...

Comment: Just a note about PyInstaller > 1.5, the _MEIPASS2 environment variable no longer exists, but was replaced with sys._MEIPASS.

Comment: I have been looking for this solution for nearly a week now! Awesome! :)